# HTTParty with proxying raises 'wrong status line'

Tags: ruby, proxy, http-status-codes, httparty

This is my **proxy credentials**, and this will successfully connect to the server:

```
❯ ssh uuuser@aaaddress -p 22                                         
  uuuser@aaaddress password: pppassword
```

Now I'm trying send request through this proxy with **HTTParty**:

```
response = HTTParty.post 'my_url', { 
        body: { "my body" },
        http_proxyaddr: aaadress,
        http_proxyport: 22,
        http_proxyuser: uuuser,
        http_proxypass: pppassword
}
```

But this request raises `wrong status line: "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3"` error. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ssh server is not an HTTP proxy. You're mixing services here.

Comment: mm therefore, to have my vps's ip from my httparty script, I should set up http connection on my vps?

Comment: You need to set up a HTTP proxy server on `aaadress` machine, not a ssh server, and tell HTTParty to connect through that proxy. This is not a programming task, it's more of a system administration task, maybe someone with experience in that area can help you set up the proxy server.